# Determine the probability of all outcomes of rolling a loaded die twice in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, dice

new to R. I have a standard 6-sided die loaded so that "4" is twice as likely as any other face, so my random variable would look something like:

X1 = {[1, 1/7], [2, 1/7], [3, 1/7], [4, 2/7], [5, 1/7], [6, 1/7]}

I would like to find the entire probability density function of a random variable (X2) that sums the result of two rolls (X1+X1), so the output would be X2 = {[2, 1/49], [3, 1/49], ... , [12, 1/49]}. The output can be a dataframe, table, or whatever you think is most appropriate.

I have attempted the following:

```
dice <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
probs <- c(1/7, 1/7, 1/7, 2/7, 1/7, 1/7) 
c <- expand.grid(probs, probs)
d <- c[,1]*c[,2]
table(d)
```

However, this obviously doesn't tie the resulting probabilities to their respective outcome. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what you've already done, one way to proceed is:

```
dice <- 1:6
probs <- c(1/7, 1/7, 1/7, 2/7, 1/7, 1/7) 

df <- data.frame(
    val = apply(expand.grid(dice, dice), 1, sum),
    prob = apply(expand.grid(probs, probs), 1, prod)
)
# solution 1: using split()/lapply()
tmp <- split(df$prob, df$val) # check this out!
res <- lapply(tmp, sum)
## solution 3: using aggregate()
res <- aggregate(prob~val, df, sum)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and showing two ways to solve it!

Comment: @Scoops If it answered your question please consider accepting the solution by clicking on checkmark next to the vote button.